# Agile methodology for small company; large projects + ticket maintenance

Tags: scrum, agile, kanban

I just joined a small IT company that was looking for a project manager. We produce one project at once; that is, we start something, we develop it, we test it, and once it's done, then we think of another one.

For this reason, I implanted scrum, as projects usually take months. However (and fortunately) previous projects are working well; therefore, receiving tickets and... "issues" that just come out.

Please, consider that we are a small team (8 people in total currently) and I cannot assign only one person for tickets (it depends on each one's skills). As far as I've seen in many books and articles, Scrum-ban would fit our needs; that is, Scrum and Kanban combined.

What do you guys think about it? Could you just give me small brief about how would it be in the day by day work?

Comment: I think this question is similar to  http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9099/how-to-allow-developers-to-get-enough-quality-development-time-while-keeping-to/9488#9488

Comment: @JJimenez If you think that this post (http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9099/how-to-allow-developers-to-get-enough-quality-development-time-while-keeping-to/9488#9488) answers your question then it would be good to mark this question as a duplicate. You may do this by clicking on the 'close' link which is displayed below the question. Thanks and good luck!